# Plot two sub-variables during a 12 month period - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

The table shows the first row with 12 month names and the values of visitors, with portuguese (Portugal) and foreigners (ESTRANGEIRO) (ignore the row with no names)

[image]

How can I plot, in ggplot2, a bar graph that shows the portuguese visitors and the foreigners visitors during the 12 month period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is better to provide some reproducible code example than to submit a screenshot, see e.g. here: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

To accomplish what you want to do, you will have to change your format a little bit. Given a dataframe that looks like yours and using `reshape2`:

```
df <- data.frame(month=factor(c("Jan","Feb","Mar"),labels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar"),ordered=TRUE),
                 portugal=c(4000,2330,3000),
                 foreigner=c(4999,2600,3244),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(reshape2)
plotdf<-melt(df)
colnames(plotdf)<-c("Month","Country","Visitors")
levels(plotdf$Country)<-c("Portgual","Foreigners")

ggplot(plotdf,aes(x=Month,y=Visitors,fill=Country)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge()) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Visitors")
```

[image: Plot]